# EJS forEach / for loop undefined issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ejs

I have the following route defined

```
    app.get("/product/:category", (req, res, next) => {
    const category = req.params.category
    let selectedProducts = []
    products.forEach(product => {
        if(product.category === category)
        selectedProducts.push(product)
    })
    res.render("category_view", {products: selectedProducts, customizationItems: customizationItems, category: category, header: category, pageType: ""});
});
```

It is sending an array of objects to the ejs file defined as "category view". Which is the following.

```
<%- include ("partials/header.ejs") %>
<div class="category-enclosure">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="category-list">
          <!-- <div class="category-bar hideme" >
            <h1><%-category%></h1>
        </div> -->
        <div class="searchbar" >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search For Product... ">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>  
        </div>
    
            <% products.forEach(item => { %>
              <div class="floating-product-img disabled" id="<%- item.id %>">
                <img src="<%- item.img %>">
              </div>
              <div class="floating-customization-menu disabled" id="<%- item.id %>">
                <div class="customize-header">
                  <h1>Chocolate Chip</h1>
                  <h2>$8.33</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="customize-body">
                  <form action="#">
                      <ul class="collection">
                        <% for(let i = 0; i < customizationItems.length; i++) { %>
                          <% if (item.toppings[i].title === customizationItems[i]) { %>
                            <li class="collection-item"> 
                              <div>
                                <p>
                                <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" checked="checked" />
                                  <span><%-item.toppings[i].title %></span>
                                </label>
                              </p>
                            </div>  
                            <div>
                              <a href=""><i class="material-icons">remove_circle_outline</i></a>
                              <p></p>
                              <a href=""><i class="material-icons">add_circle_outline</i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <h2><%-item.toppings[i].amount %></h2>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                            
                         <% } else { %>
                          <li class="collection-item"> 
                            <div>
                              <p>
                              <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" />
                                <span><%-customizationItems[i] %></span>
                              </label>
                            </p>
                          </div>  
                          <div>
                            <a href=""><i class="material-icons">remove_circle_outline</i></a>
                            <p></p>
                            <a href=""><i class="material-icons">add_circle_outline</i></a>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <h2></h2>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        
                         
                         <% }%>
                      <% } %>
                      </ul>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="customize-footer">
                  <div>
                    <h2>Total</h2>
                    <h2>$21.00</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="customize-footer-btns">
                      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn cancle-btn">Cancle</a>
                      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Add to Cart</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card category-card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light product-img">
                  <img src="<%-item.img%>">
                  <i class="image-expand-button fas fa-expand-alt" id="<%- item.id %>"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content category-card-content">
                    <div class="category-card-title">
                      <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4"><%- item.name %></span>
                      <p>$<%- item.price %></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-btns">
                    <div>
                      <i class="fas fa-angle-up activator"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <a href=""><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
                    </div>
                   
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                  <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4"><%- item.name %><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                  <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
                  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">Add to Cart</a>
                  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small customize-btn" id="<%- item.id %>">Customize</a>

                </div>
              </div>
            <%}) %>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%- include ("partials/footer.ejs") %>
```

Here is the array of objects:

```
const products = [
{
    id: "1",
    name: "chocolate chip",
    category: "cookies",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever",
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486428128344-5413e434ad35?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
    price: 6.33,
    toppings: [{name: "cherries", amount: 2} , {name: "nuts", amount: 1}, {name: "chocolate flakes", amount: 1}]

},
{
    id: "2",
    name: "peanut butter",
    category: "cookies",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever",
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519869491916-8ca6f615d6bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
    price: 4.77,
    toppings: [{title: "cherries", amount: 1} , {title: "nuts", amount: 1}, {title: "chocolate flakes", amount: 1}]
},
{
    id: "3",
    name: "chocolate chip",
    category: "cookies",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever",
    img: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486427944299-d1955d23e34d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
    price: 6.33,
    toppings: [{title: "cherries", amount: 1} , {title: "nuts", amount: 1}, {title: "chocolate flakes", amount: 1}]

},
```

];

Here is the second array:

```
const customizationItems =  ["cholate drizzle", "chocolate flakes", "strawberries", "cherries", "nuts"]
```

Inside this ejs file I am looping over an object called products using a forEach statement. This renders out a element for each object in the array. Inside this loop I also have a "for loop" which is used to compare an array under the property "customizationItems" to another array which is a property of an item of the containing forEach statement referenced like so "item.toppings[i].name". However, this property is unrefined on page render.

I've verified that this property does not equal undefined as long as the "I" does not surpass the length of the "toppings array". Normally if I compare to arrays of strings there is no issue and the else statement is triggered due to the undefined value because the two arrays are at different lengths.

I am wondering why the else statement is not triggered rendering an alternative element when the value of "item.toppings[i].name" equals undefined.

Here is the browser error:

```
TypeError: /home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/views/category_view.ejs:28
    26|                       <ul class="collection">
    27|                         <% for(let i = 0; i < customizationItems.length; i++) { %>
 >> 28|                           <% if ( item.toppings[i].title === customizationItems[i]) { %>
    29|                             <li class="collection-item"> 
    30|                               <div>
    31|                                 <p>

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at products.forEach.item (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/views/category_view.ejs:31:30)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/views/category_view.ejs:16:17)
    at category_view (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:691:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/devindavis/Documents/webdev/bakery-project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the error returned by ejs.render:

```
    27|                         <% for(let i = 0; i < customizationItems.length; i++) { %>
 >> 28|                           <% if ( item.toppings[i].title === customizationItems[i]) { %>
```

As you noted in your question, you're iterating over the `customizationItems` array using `i`. But then you are using that same index to look at elements of a different array called `toppings`. As a result, trying to dereference `item.toppings[i].title` is likely to throw an exception - going out of bounds on an array in Javascript does not throw an exception, but dereferencing an undefined value will.

To break this down a bit more:

Let's say `item.toppings` is an array with 2 elements, while customizationItems has 4.
When `i = 2`, `item.toppings[i]` is trying to fetch the third item from an array of two items. This is called going **out of bounds**, and it returns undefined in javascript.

So in this example, the expression `item.toppings[i].title` when `item.toppings[i]` is undefined as we just discussed, trying to fetch the value of the `title` property from undefined throws an exception.

Instead, you should match array iteration to the elements that are being referenced inside the loop. For example, find topping titles that are the same as customization items, we can loop through both arrays like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < customizationItems.length; i++) {
    for(let n = 0; n < item.toppings.length; n++) {
        if ( item.toppings[n].title === customizationItems[i]) {
            // do stuff
```

This could also be written like this which eliminates the numerical index variables entirely:

```
for(let customizationItem of customizationItems) {
    for(let topping of item.toppings) {
        if ( topping.title === customizationItem ) {
            // do stuff
```

This might make it easier to see how we are looping over both arrays and comparing their contents.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! This makes a lot of sense. So I compare each item in the shorter array against the the longer array without allowing the shorter array to compare undefined values.

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited it a bit at the end because I think it makes the concept a bit clearer.